# where the file is saved on the internal storage

Tags: android, internal-storage

i am developing against Asus Nexus 7, and i do not have SD-card and i am trying to create a file in the internal storage as shown below in the code.
when i run the App there are no files created and aslo i do not know where the files are saved..

as the below log output states, the file "TEST.txt" is created under /storage/emulated/0/CAN_BUS

but i do not have /storage/..

where the file is save?

NOTE: the code posted is taken from Android dev website

**log output**:

```
 +++++ isExternalStorageMounted() +++++
11-26 13:31:11.264 17601-17601/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: isExternalStorageMounted(): -> media state: mounted
11-26 13:31:11.265 17601-17601/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: dir: /storage/emulated/0/CAN_BUS already exists
11-26 13:31:11.266 17601-17601/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: file: TEST.txt already exists
```

**code**:

```
private final static String DIR_NAME = "CAN_BUS";
private final static String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

if (IOCtrl.isExternalStorageMounted()) {

        File dir = new File(IOCtrl.ROOT_DIR + File.separator + IOCtrl.DIR_NAME);
        boolean dirCreated = dir.mkdirs();

        if (dirCreated) {
            Log.d(TAG, "dir: " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " created");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "dir: " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " already exists");
        }

        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        boolean fileExists = file.exists();

        if (fileExists) {
            Log.d(TAG, "file: " + fileName + " already exists");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "file: " + fileName + " will be created");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, CSubTag.subBullet("createFile", "Error creating file: " + e.getMessage()));
                return null;
            }
        }

        return file;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, CSubTag.msg("createFile", "media storage is not available"));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `as the below log output states, the file "TEST.txt" is created under /storage/emulated/0/CAN_BUS

but i do not have /storage/..` That message refers to the **emulator** storage. On your **device**, the file should be on your current storage root, under a folder called `CAN_BUS`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein but on the device there is nothing as well...any suggestions please

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I found it... i had to restart the device

Answer (score 0):

your file is saved in internal storage of your device. You can see using DDMS Tool in Eclipse or Android Studio .

Helpful link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825304/Accessing-internal-data-on-Android-device